# querystring with codeigniter and facebox plugin

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebox, request.querystring

I am  beginner in CI,
i used facebox plugin for loading a page [query result ] in CodeIgniter,
ie select all the datas from a table.
Its working properly, 
The problem is i need to display only the data on a specific day,ie from the user input.

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox({
        loadingImage : '<?=base_url();?>facebox/loading.gif',
        closeImage   : '<?=base_url();?>facebox/closelabel.gif'
      })
    })
  </script> 
...........
....
<a href="<?=base_url();?>admission/details" rel="facebox" >view details </a>
```

if i add a text box to this page how can i pass the value to that controller?
with out changing the facebox properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="fb1" href="<?=base_url();?>admission/details" rel="facebox" >view details </a>
<input type="text" onchange="updateFB('#fb1',this.value)">
<script>
function updateFB(el,val){
    $(el).attr('href',"<?=base_url();?>admission/details/"+val);
}
</script>

//controller
function admission(){
    $date = $this->uri->segment(3);
....
```